# Castle WCF Integration Channel Closing

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor, integration, castle

I've been under the impression that releasing the component for my WCF service connection would close the channel associated with the component. However, consider the following:

```
// In some installer class
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
    container.Register(
        Component.For<IMyService>()
            .Forward<IMyOtherService>()
            .AsWcfClient(WcfEndpoint.FromConfiguration("WSHttpBinding_IMyService"))
            .LifeStyle.Transient
    );
}

// In some local class enabling constructor injection for IMyService
public void DoStuff() {
    IWindsorContainer container = GetContainer();

    var myService = container.Resolve<IMyService>();

    if(myService != null) {
        container.Release(myService);

        // I had always thought this shouldn't work
        // as the channel should be closed - but its
        // state is Opened
        var foo = myService.GetSomething( ... );

        DoOtherStuff(foo);
        ...
    }
}
```

I've tried various lifestyles including my own that inherits `AbstractLifestyleManager` and calls `base.Release(context)` but the channel remains open after the component is released. Is this expected behavior?

So how do I close then WCF connection channel/proxy properly when using Castle WCF Integration?

**Edit**

Removed mention of using `LifeStyle.Singleton` (where channel is released when container is disposed) as using other lifestyles have yielded the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

`container.Release(myService);` does not release your singleton component. Channel will be released along with the component which in case of singletons means when the container gets disposed.

Comment: I've tried other LifeStyles including `Transient` and still have the same result.

Comment: What build of the facility are you running? I'm fairly certain this ought to work

Comment: Assembly v2.5.0.0 - File v2.5.0.82 - Product v2.5.0.82

Comment: ok, I think you might want to report this to the issue tracker, as it seems that is a bug

Comment: Ok, at least this directionally validates that I'm not crazy (at least not cuz of this) - thank you for the responses! I'll report this to the issue tracker soon.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this? I seem to have an issue in live whereby I get thousands of channels stuck in memory

Comment: @Mark909 Sorry for the late response, but this issue has been resolved.

Comment: Could you tell me what version of Castle Windsor was this resolved in, please? We're having the same issue and if we could just upgrade to a newer version of Windsor that would be awesome.